# Best approach to combine repositories logic

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

**Let's suppose I have 2 `repositories`:**

- first is responsible for creating job and return `jobId`
- second is responsible for creating log and take `jobId` as argument

**My goal is to:**

- save `Job` and `Log` simultaneously
- prevent situation when in case of error only `Job` would be saved without `Log`

#### What is the most recommended way to get desired result?

I prepared 3 cases which came to my mind but if you see better alternative please share it.

- **option 1 (getting result and save changes in controller)**

```cs
public class JobRepository : IJobRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    
    public JobRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Guid CreateJob()
    {
        var job = new Job { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        _context.Jobs.Add(job);
        return job.Id;
    }
}
// ...
public class LogRepository : ILogRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    
    public LogRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void CreateLog(Guid id)
    {
        var log = new Log { Jobid = id };
        _context.Logs.Add(log);
    }
}
// ...
public class JobsController : Controller
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly IJobRepository _jobRepository;
    private readonly ILogRepository _logRepository;

    public JobsController(Context context, JobRepository jobRepository, ILogRepository logRepository)
    {
        _context = context;
        _jobRepository = jobRepository;
        _logRepository = logRepository
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var id = _jobRepository.CreateJob();
        _logRepository.CreateLog(id);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

- **option 2 (inject one repository into another)**

```cs
public class JobRepository : IJobRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly ILogRepository _logRepository;
    
    public JobRepository(Context context, ILogRepository logRepository)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void CreateJob()
    {
        var job = new Job { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        _context.Jobs.Add(job);
        _logRepository.CreateLog(job.Id);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
// ...
public class LogRepository : ILogRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    
    public LogRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void CreateLog(Guid id)
    {
        var log = new Log { Jobid = id };
        _context.Logs.Add(log);
    }
}
// ...
public class JobsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IJobRepository _jobRepository;

    public JobsController(JobRepository jobRepository)
    {
        _jobRepository = jobRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
         _jobRepository.CreateJob();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

- **option 3 (do not use context in controller but declare `Save` method in each repo)**

````cs
public class JobRepository : IJobRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    
    public JobRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Guid CreateJob()
    {
        var job = new Job { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        _context.Jobs.Add(job);
        return job.Id;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
// ...
public class LogRepository : ILogRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    
    public LogRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void CreateLog(Guid id)
    {
        var log = new Log { Jobid = id };
        _context.Logs.Add(log);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
// ...
public class JobsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IJobRepository _jobRepository;
    private readonly ILogRepository _logRepository;

    public JobsController(JobRepository jobRepository, ILogRepository logRepository)
    {
        _jobRepository = jobRepository;
        _logRepository = logRepository
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var id = _jobRepository.CreateJob();
        _logRepository.CreateLog(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Unfortunately none of them is correct. If one of  the `save` command fails then the other is not rolled back. So both changes should be tackled under the same DbContext to be able to participate in a same transaction.

Comment: plus, it seems you're using `EF` as `SaveChanges` exists in `DbContext`, if that's true, then the best approach would be to override `SaveChanges` to log entities changes.

Comment: This question seems better suited to StackOverflow or SoftwareEngineering.SE. This isn't a request for a code review.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you have organised your database code in such a way that you have one repository per table. With this *pattern* you'll eventually always reach the point you are at right now. Just create a single repository by database with all the queries you need to execute. You'll then be able to create proper transactions and handle inserts without scratching your head how to keep the data consistent.

Yet another option would be to add a trigger to the *job-table* at the database level and handle writing the log there but I'm not a fan of this approach.